# Edit Current Object's SQL in MS Access through VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using MS Access 2013 trying to edit the SQL of the current query that is being displayed on the screen. I can get the name of the current query using `qName = Application.CurrentObjectName` however **the current query is not saved, nor do I want it to be saved.**

I know that using something like below, I can get the SQL of a **saved** query *and* modify that query.

```
Dim qd As QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(qName)
qd.SQL = "Select Customers.ID From Customers"
```

However, the query that I want to modify is not saved, but rather just being worked on. What I want to do is access the SQL which is visible in SQL view, read that into a variable, and modify it. I am not sure how to proceed and would appreciate some help. (What I have tried is summarized above.)

(In case you are curious. The queries I am working on may be new or may be being modified from saved queries; saving could overwrite something which I am not yet finished with/is not working, thus causing more issues.)

Comment: If it's not saved, it can't be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your unsaved new query is open in Datasheet View, you can retrieve its SQL like this:

```vb
MsgBox Application.Screen.ActiveDatasheet.RecordSource
```

However if you want to modify that SQL within its current query window, I can't help you.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to access! You said that I can't modify the SQL within the current query window, is there a workaround that you might suggest? (Even if there is not, the answer you posted at least lets me copy the SQL and move it around freely.)

Comment: The workaround I would choose is a saved scratchpad `QueryDef` ... *qryDisardMe*.  Modify it's SQL property as needed.  You could delete it when finished if you want.  It may not be elegant, but it's easy.

Comment: That sounds feasible and addresses my concerns regarding numerous queries and overwriting. Thank you for the quick reply. I am marking this as the answer.